# Datomic - select entities with highest in some attribute

Tags: search, max, datomic

Let's say I have a list of movies and I can get them all this way:

```
[:find ?year ?title ?rating
 :where
 [?Movie :movie/year ?year  ]
 [?Movie :movie/year ?title ]
 [?Movie :movie/year ?rating]]
```

How can I further restrict this to get only the movie with the highest rating?  I feel like I want something like...

```
[:find ?year ?title ?rating
 :where
 [?Movie :movie/year ?year  ]
 [?Movie :movie/year ?title ]
 [?Movie :movie/year ?rating]
 [(= ?rating (max ?rating)  ]]
```

But obviously that won't do what I want =)  Tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's OK to do this sort of thing with two queries in Datomic. Having peers cache databases locally means the pressure to get as much done in one query is relieved a bit.

```
[:find (max ?year) .
 :where [?m :movie/year ?year]]
```

Followed by:

```
[:find ?maxyear ?title ?rating
 :in $ ?maxyear
 :where [?m :movie/year ?maxyear]
        [?m :movie/title ?title]
        [?m :movie/rating ?rating]]
```

Is ok. The chained queries in Clojure could look like:

```
(let [db (d/db conn)]
  (->>
    (d/q '[:find (max ?year) .
           :where [?m :movie/year ?year]]
         db)
    (d/q '[:find ?maxyear ?title ?rating
           :in $ ?maxyear
           :where [?m :movie/year ?maxyear]
                  [?m :movie/title ?title]
                  [?m :movie/rating ?rating]]
         db)))
```

Notice we only get the db value from the connection once in the let binding. It *is* possible to use collection returning functions to get the result you've mentioned with the right constraints, but this may not behave how you'd expect - as with this example that gets the latest Beatles release:

```
(d/q '[:find (max ?tuple)
       :where [?e :artist/name "The Beatles"]
              [?a :release/artists ?e]
              [?a :release/year ?y]
              [?a :release/name ?n]
              [(vector ?y ?n) ?tuple]]
      (d/db conn))
```

This relies on the implicit ordering from the first element, but how does it behave for multiple maxes? This returns:

```
[[[2011 "Love"]]]
```

But without max, we can see the one pulled by max was not unique:

```
[[2011 "1"]] [[2011 "Love"]]
```

If you know how many to expect, you could set, e.g.:

```
:find (max 2 ?tuple)
```

But this is taking us down a road best avoided. For most instances it makes sense to prefer the simple, more robust case of combining queries.